# Solving a non-linear system with 3 variables (kinematics)

Tags: kinematics

I'm trying to find the parametric solutions for a 2-dimensional set of kinematics equations.

My params are:

- `Δx, Δy` - initial and target positions.
- `Vx, Vy` - initial velocity.
- `A` - the acceleration magnitude.

My variables are:

- `t` - time to reach x1, y1.
- `Ax` - acceleration in the x axis.
- `Ay` - acceleration in the y axis.

Given this and the kinematic equations I have this set:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{l}
a_x^{2}+a_y^2=A^2 \\ 
Δx = v_xt + a_xt^2 \\
Δy = v_yt + a_yt^2
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

I can't seem to find a technic to solve this set. Even when putting this in Wolfram Alpha with the parameters, it doesn't provide me a solution.

Is there even a way to solve this?
Thanks.

Comment: is there an $A_x,A_y$ in your System?

Comment: Yes, wrote them as `ax` and `ay`.